# Does spark standalone cluster require homogeneous machines?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to run graphx app on cluster which includes machines with different amount of RAM.
For now I tried to use spark standalone cluster. But it seems I cannot adjust spark.executor.memory property for each machine. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

For me, if you set the option spark.executor.memory manually, your tasks will be launched on the workers which have at least the amount of RAM you have manually given.

So by using this option, you need to have an uniform cluster.

By default, each worker uses all the RAM available on its machine (minus 1Go for the OS) and you can only limit the amount of RAM you want to use. I don't know if it's what you're looking for with the term "adjust".

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html (search on SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY)