# How to allot different memories to different workers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, master-slave

I want to allot different memories to different workers of a cluster in spark.
When specifying conf, we can write **.set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")** which will allot 2 gb to all respective workers. But how to allot different memory to different workers.

For example, I want to give 1g to one worker and 2g to remaining workers. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: To my knowledge it is not possible. Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: I have nodes with different memories and I am constrained by the node with the least memory. That's why I wanted to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481404/does-spark-standalone-cluster-require-homogeneous-machines)

1. It seems it is not possible to provide different memory constraints.
2. However documentation says that if you do not provide any       constraints, then all memory of the machine will be used. Thus,         maybe if you have different machines it can uses different amount of         RAM on each machine

.